# How do I use two buttons in Controller? Each button has a tableview?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

im using two buttons in my controller
when i press button1 it should show tableview related to button 1 
and when i press button 2 it shows tableview related to button 2 
how can I achieve this?

Comment: Just use a `bool` and based on that populate your `tableView` data in `data source` methods.

Comment: Do you want to use single tableView or 2 tableViews?

Comment: Also, add the code of the model and tableView dataSource.

Comment: well here i need guidance that should i use two tableViews or single tableView with two cells will work? @PGDev

Comment: You can definitely use a single tableView as long as you can handle different dataSource for both of them. Add more details so I can update the answer that I added.

Comment: since im new to this can you please refer some tutorial  on handling the dataSources @PGDev

Comment: Not the tutorial, but I've added an answer that'll guide you in the right direction. See if you can relate with that.

Comment: according to your code it will change the value of the labels..my task is when I press button 1 it presents a tableView with different design and button 2 has  tableView with completely different design.How do I design their cells @PGDev

Comment: Have you worked with designing a single UITableViewCell earlier?

Comment: yes i have worked and working good butt stuck at this point

Comment: Then create another cell with a different identifier. And use that like I did. In my code, I'm not just changing the label. Look at the cellIdentifier. They are different. Changing the label is just an example.

Comment: @PGDev i got this all that issue was using the same identifiers

Comment: Same identifiers won't result in different cells. Kindly read about the use of reusableIdentifier of a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create an `enum` that'll keep a track of what `data` and `cell` should be loaded in the `tableView`, i.e.

```
enum Source {
    case button1
    case button2
}
```

Now, you must have 2 `arrays` that'll use to load the `tableView` as per the `source`.

**For example:**

```
class VC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var arr1 = ["one", "two"]
    var arr2 = ["three", "four"]
    var source = Source.button1

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch source {
        case .button1:
            return arr1.count
        case .button2:
            return arr2.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch source {
        case .button1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = arr1[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        case .button2:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = arr2[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Now, create `@IBAction` for both the `buttons`, update the `source` and reload the `tableView` on `button` taps.

```
@IBAction func onTapButton1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.source = .button1
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func onTapButton2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.source = .button2
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you're looking for, is `SegmentedControl`.

You should use ViewController as base for your page, add segmented control on top, add tableView after that. Then use segmented control to control the source of your table. Your code should look like that:

```
switch (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex ) {
    case 0:
        yourDataCollection = someService.getData(); // depends on selected index
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    case 1:
        yourDataCollection = someService.getSomeOtherData();
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    default:
        return
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use buttons instead of segmented control, you can create a bool/Int value and store it on button tap. The code will be almost the same.